# Is there a policy in azure that ensures database auditing is enabled by default

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Need help with the policy in azure that ensure database auditing is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This can be accomplished through [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about SQL, see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/policy-reference

There are two policies with different effects:

- Auditing on SQL server should be enabled (AuditIfNotExists, Disabled)
- Deploy Auditing on SQL servers (DeployIfNotExists)